# Cannot use dictionary on comments in iOS App

Tags: feature-request, comments, ios-app

While I am reading the user comments for questions or answers in the iOS version of Stack Exchange app, I found that I cannot highlight a word to use dictionary. I can do that in question and answer paragraphs.

This feature should be very useful. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Well a workaround is the use the "copy" button and do it in notes or somewhere else, but that's a fair bit of effort.

Comment: What happens exactly? There's an issue on Mac with comments and the dictionary and I'm wondering if it's the same one...

Answer (score -1):

[Cai suggested this in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287693/cannot-use-dictionary-on-comments-in-ios-app#comment933651_287693):

You could use the copy button after highlighting to move it into Notes or any other word platform and then use the Dictionary. It does take a little effort.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the feature request, it's a work around.

Comment: it's not a convenient way to read the comments with dictionary. it's better if we can do it within the app.